# Generating hyperlink using Hive UDF

Tags: hive

So I have one field as IP address. I want to generate hyperlink to it so that one can directly redirect to Information regarding IP.

http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/#Some Ip Address.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> select CONCAT(CAST('http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address#' AS
    > String),'/',Ip_address)                                        
    > from tablea;                                                        
OK
http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address#/192.168.0.233
```

You have to right click on link and click open link to redirect the information link. If you want to do on single click than you have to implement hyperlink logic on front end side.